# Starting an element at certain coloumn within Susy grid

Tags: susy

What the best way to position an element say 2 columns in.  Is there a short hand syntax like

```
span (6 at 2)
```

Which i've tried but doesn't work.
Or is the correct way to apply a left margin.  Also can you get the span count to start from the right?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`span (6 at 2)` works if you are using `output: isolate` — because isolation calculates position from the left edge for all elements. With the standard `float` output, you have to `push` or `pull` elements where you want them. Those push and pull the element from their default place in the flow (using margins).

```
@include span(6);
@inlude push(2);
```